# In MFC why do I need to create a global instance of CWinApp?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc

Why the constructor of my derived CWinApp should be invoked before main function starts?
Why can't it be something like:

```
int WinMain()
{
   CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
   // etc ...
}
```

I'm looking for the technical reason that forces this behavior.
Edit:
To make clearer - If I'm using win32 API without MFC the main window is created inside WinMain so what is the difference?

Comment: Presumably so that the constructor for `CWinApp` is run *before* the `main` function runs. But I'm not actually sure; I've never tried doing this to see if it works. Have you?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I tried. The application crashes inside AfxWinMain

Comment: Ah yes, exactly as Frederic's answer predicts. The constructor for `CWinApp` is setting the value of some state variables, expected by `AfxWinMain`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, that's because the MFC designers decided to provide the application entry point ([WinMain()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx), not `main()`) in the library itself, so users would not have to write one.

The application's initialization and termination logic is then relocated to the `InitInstance()`and `ExitInstance()` methods of the instance of a user-provided `CWinApp`-derived singleton. This instance has to exist before `WinMain()` runs, because it calls the aforementioned methods (and `Run()` to enter the message loop) and uses it to store state (like the `nCmdShow` argument it receives).

Defining the `CWinApp`-derived instance in the global scope is an easy way to ensure it does exist by the time `WinMain()` runs.

[This article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c4131/MFC-Under-the-Hood.htm) has additional details on what happens under the hood when an MFC application starts.